# ASP.NET Application getting errors when I deploy to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications, iis-7, iis-7.5

I created a web application in Visual Studio 2010 and when I run it on my local PC via Visual Studio, everything runs just fine.

When I try to copy thew files onto my server to deploy it, I get errors.

Here's what I did:

1. Created a new website in IIS. Path is "C:\Apps\PLOT\ServerStats".
2. Started it.
3. Checked ASP.NET authorization rules, and it is consistent with what I have in my web.config file.

   `<authorization>< allow users="usmanas" />< /authorization>`
4. Checked the Connection Strings section and all my connections are consistent with what I have in my web.config.
5. Checked Authentication section in IIS section and it says Windows Authentication is enabled, just as my web.config says.

When I try to browse the website, it says "Server Error in '/' Application." and "An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed."

My web.config in the root directory of the application DOES have this set...`<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>`

Can someone please help me get my application set up?????????

Comment: First of all you should set <customErrors mode="Off"/> to see the actual error message, otherwise it's hard to understand the reason. Remember to put it back to "RemoteOnly" when the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS_IUSRS has to have read priviledges on your folder.